# How to configure putty multiple with jumpboxes

Tags: putty, ssh-tunnel

At my company we have a strict security policy and to access my server i need to use different jumpboxes like this:

1. **jump_box_1** (has public access)
2. **jump_box_2** (has private access)
3. **my_server** (here is my database)
4. **public_server** (has access to my_server)

So far i managed to access **my_server** starting from jump_box_1 with putty and multiple tunnels like this:

**1.** start a ssh command to open a port on jump_box_1:

**ssh -L 2222:jump_box_2:22 my_user@jump_box_1**

**2.** start putty session configured like this(this 3 pictures are from the same connection):

[image: putty configuration]

and now i can access my database with:

**host: localhost**

**port: 1521**

What i want is to get rid of putty and use only ssh commands so in the end to automate all of this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix it with one ssh command like this, i hope it help someone:

```
ssh -fN -L 2222:jump_box_2:22 <user>@jump_box_1 && ssh -fN -p 2222 -L 2223:public_server:22 <user_jump_2>@localhost && ssh -p 2223 -L 1521:my_server :1521 <user_public_server>@localhost
```